# jQuery zIndex div display problem

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am trying to set the z-Index through Jquery, but I need every DIV except for one called importantdiv to be from 0-100. The only problem is that importantdiv gets a z-index of 40 instead of 510? what Did I do wrong in my jquery code?

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var zIndexNumber = 100;
        $('div').each(function() {
            $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
            zIndexNumber -= 10;
        });
        $('#importantdiv').css('zIndex', 510);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's working fine with me: http://jsfiddle.net/naveed_ahmad/vYYkX/ See the demo

Comment: Inspect the element using developer tools obviously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(function() {
    var zIndexNumber = 100;
    $('div').not($('#importantdiv')).each(function() {
        $(this).css('z-index', zIndexNumber);
        zIndexNumber -= 10;
    });
    $('#importantdiv').css('z-index', 510);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For one thing it's:

```
$(this).css('z-index', zIndexNumber);
```

not

```
$(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
```

Answer (score -1):

It probably happens because the "each" loop function runs in a separate thread that smash overwrites the importantdiv since the code splits into two threads kinda. You could put an If inside the loop to check for importantdiv and if so skip it.